# How to url encode matched path segment in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have an API endpoint to retrieve the owner of a file within the project. I am trying to URL-encode the project path and file name and subsequently proxy-pass them to the backend server.

```
location ~ /api/project_path/(.*)/file/(.*)/owner {
  # url encode $1 into $encoded_projectpath
  # url encode $2 into $encoded_file
  proxy_pass http://backend/$encoded_projectpath/$encoded_file/owner;
}
```

Example

```
curl http://localhost/api/project_path/my/project/path/file/my/file/name/owner
# nginx proxy-pass to http://backend/my%2Fproject%2Fpath/my%2Ffile%2Fname/owner
```

Is there a built-in method in Nginx to address this issue? If not, I plan to explore the option of using njs. Thank you.

**FYI** 
Here is my njs solution. But, I don't recommend it because it's unextendable to other endpoints.

```
// http.js
function urlencode_projectpath(r) {
  let pattern = "(?<=/api/project_path/)(.*)/file/(.*)/upload_url"
  let url = r.variables.request_uri
  let project_path = url.match(pattern)[0]
  
  return encodeURIComponent(project_path)
}

function urlencode_file(r) {
  let pattern = "(?<=/api/project_path/)(.*)/file/(.*)/upload_url"
  let url = r.variables.request_uri
  let file= url.match(pattern)[1]
  
  return encodeURIComponent(file)
}
export default { urlencode_projectpath, urlencode_file }
```

```
# nginx.conf

http {
  js_import /etc/nginx/conf.d/http.js;
  js_set $encoded_projectpath http.urlencode_projectpath;
  js_set $encoded_file http.urlencode_file;
  server {
    location ~ /api/project_path/(.*)/file/(.*)/owner {
      proxy_pass http://backend/$encoded_projectpath/$encoded_file/owner;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nginx should automatically URL-encode any characters that need to be encoded. Unfortunately for you, `/` does not need to be encoded, furthermore, many backends would normally interpret `%2F` and `/` exactly the same. One possible solution would be to use a `map` of regular expressions. Alternatively, move the parameters into the query string. But the short answer is no.

Comment: Thanks!. Your response has made me to reconsider my endpoint design. I'm referencing to gitlab api (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-file-from-repository) and re-designing mine.

Comment: Is it a common practice to perform URL encoding for clients in proxy, or should clients be responsible for this task?